# how to use default locale in symfony3.4 routes

Tags: symfony, routes, locale

I want to open my websites like these:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Works)
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/ (Works)
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/mrg (Works)
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/mrg (Doesn't Work)

So I put this code in `routing.yml`:

```
teach:
   resource: "@TeachBundle/Controller/"
   type:     annotation
   prefix:   /{_locale}
   requirements:
       _locale: "|en|fa"
```

and my controller is like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/mrg")
 */
public function mrgAction(Request $request)
{
     $lang=$request->getLocale();

     return new Response("<html><body>Your language: <b> $lang </b></body></html>");
}
```

All urls worked but `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mrg` doesn't work and returns:

> No route found for "GET /mrg"

I need use default language for example if I try to open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mrg` then open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/mrg`.

Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`{_locale}`

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/mrg")
 */
public function mrgAction(Request $request)
{
     $lang=$request->getLocale();

     return new Response("<html><body>Your language: <b> $lang </b></body></html>");
}
```

[Setting a Default Locale](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#setting-a-default-locale)

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

If doesn't work, Can You show your `app/config/routing.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `defaults` option to your routing configuration to set the default locale if it's not set in your controllers `@Route`s:

```
teach:
    resource: "@TeachBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: "|en|fa"
    defaults:
        _locale: 'en' # or '%locale%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use : BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle

https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle

```
use BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Annotation\I18nRoute;

class NoPrefixController
{
    /**
     * @I18nRoute({ "en": "/welcome", "fr": "/bienvenue", "de": "/willkommen" }, name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction() { }
}
```